# Git: save files history after moving directory

Tags: git, android-studio

I want to move directory to another directory with history of files under git.

[Now i have "defects" folder with classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfqob.png)

I want to move it into "inspections" directory like this:

[After moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAEx4.png)

But after moving i lose all my git history of files in "defects" directory.

[Show history gimme an empty result for any file after moving directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csVOA.png)

I tried moving with refractor in Android studio and also `git mv defects inspections`. Both gave me the same result: "show history" becames empty for any files after moving. 
I know that it's not first question by this theme, but i'm really don't know what i'm doing wrong. Please explain me :)

Answer (score 2):

Git does not keep track of files, it keeps track of content. In its brain, files are just metadata. If you ask it for the history a file, it looks up that content in the current snapshot, then tracks the content backward through the history.

If you want to track content across a move, you have to start from its current location and explicitly tell git to look for moved files.

```
git log --follow -- <file>
```

should get you where you're going.

Note that git doesn't explicitly track move data, but infers it based on a similarity index. If more than 50% of a file has changed, git will not recognize it as moved by default.

Comment: thanks for the interesting answer. Your command show me full history off file, but after moving i lose it anyway. My problem was that i didn't commit it after moving. I really didn't know about it.